# How to pass data separated to arrays with the same key name in an array in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, join

I'm working with React js and Javascript.

I have this object literal:

```
artistList = {
    artist: [
        0:{name: 'Quirby', role: 'main'},
        1:{name: 'Jose', role: 'feature'}
    ],
    writer: [
        0:{name: 'Erik', role: 'publisher'},
        1:{name: 'Cairo', role: 'composer'},
        2:{name: 'Erik', role: 'song_writer'}
    ]
}
```

and i want to join the roles in an array of writers that have the same name like this:

```
artistList = {
    artist: [
        0:{name: 'Quirby', role: 'main'},
        1:{name: 'Jose', role: 'feature'}
    ],
    writer: [
        0:{name: 'Erik', role: ['publisher', 'song_writer']},
        1:{name: 'Cairo', role: 'composer'}
    ]
}
```

any ideas?

I want to join the roles of the same writer in a new array, i don't know how to check they have the same name and transform my array.

Comment: You haven't shown any research or effort here... that part is important

Comment: are you using any tool libraries like lodash or ramda?

Comment: `artistList` is not a JSON string, it’s an object, with some arrays in it.